# How to set limited adapter list in Android

Tags: java, android, android-adapter

In my application i use **ArrayAdapter** and i want show just **6 item**.
I write below code in `adapter` :

```
@Override
public int getCount() {
    return 6;
}
```

**but when go page and if items size is 0 show me this error :**

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                   Process: com.app.test, PID: 7264
                                                                   java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0
                                                                       at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:411)
                                                                       at com.app.test.Adapters.AuctionDetailBidListAdapter.getView(AuctionDetailBidListAdapter.java:46)
                                                                       at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:3170)
                                                                       at android.widget.ListView.makeAndAddView(ListView.java:2140)
                                                                       at android.widget.ListView.fillDown(ListView.java:762)
                                                                       at android.widget.ListView.fillFromTop(ListView.java:826)
                                                                       at android.widget.ListView.layoutChildren(ListView.java:1893)
                                                                       at android.widget.AbsListView.onLayout(AbsListView.java:2942)
                                                                       at android.view.View.layout(View.java:18878)
                                                                       at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5953)
                                                                       at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1741)
                                                                       at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1585)
                                                                       at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1494)
                                                                       at android.view.View.layout(View.java:18878)
                                                                       at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5953)
                                                                       at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.onLayout(ViewPager.java:1766)
                                                                       at android.view.View.layout(View.java:18878)
                                                                       at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5953)
                                                                       at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1741)
                                                                       at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1585)
                                                                       at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1494)
                                                                       at android.view.View.layout(View.java:18878)
                                                                       at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5953)
                                                                       at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.onLayout(ViewPager.java:1766)
                                                                       at android.view.View.layout(View.java:18878)
                                                                       at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5953)
                                                                       at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1741)
                                                                       at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1585)
                                                                       at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1494)
                                                                       at android.view.View.layout(View.java:18878)
                                                                       at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5953)
                                                                       at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1741)
                                                                       at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1585)
                                                                       at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1494)
                                                                       at android.view.View.layout(View.java:18878)
                                                                       at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5953)
                                                                       at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1741)
                                                                       at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1585)
                                                                       at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1494)
                                                                       at android.view.View.layout(View.java:18878)
                                                                       at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5953)
                                                                       at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:323)
                                                                       at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:261)
                                                                       at android.view.View.layout(View.java:18878)
                                                                       at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5953)
                                                                       at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1741)
                                                                       at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1585)
                                                                       at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1494)
                                                                       at android.view.View.layout(View.java:18878)
                                                                       at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5953)
                                                                       at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:323)
                                                                       at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:261)
                                                                       at android.view.View.layout(View.java:18878)
                                                                       at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5953)
                                                                       at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1741)
                                                                       at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1585)
                                                                       at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1494)
                                                                       at android.view.View.layout(View.java:18878)
                                                                       at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5953)
                                                                       at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:323)
                                                                       at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:261)
                                                                       at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.onLayout(DecorView.java:934)
                                                                       at android.view.View.layout(View.java:18878)
                                                                       at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5953)
01-02 15:37:05.687 7264-7264/com.app.test E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:2684)
                                                                       at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:2400)
                                                                       at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1537)
                                                                       at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:7183)
                                                                       at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:959)
                                                                       at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:734)
                                                                       at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:670)
                                                                       at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:945)
                                                                       at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
                                                                       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6776)
                                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1518)
                                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1408)
```

How can i fix it?

**Adapter code:**

```
public class AuctionDetailBidListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private TextView edtUserName, time, price;
    private ImageView User, line1;

    public AuctionDetailBidListAdapter(@NonNull Context context, @LayoutRes int resource, @NonNull ArrayList<Bid> objects) {
        super(context, resource, objects);
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, @Nullable View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {
        View v = View.inflate(context, layout, null);
        Bid model = (Bid) datas.get(position);

        edtUserName = v.findViewById(R.id.edtUserName);
        line1 = v.findViewById(R.id.line1);
        time = v.findViewById(R.id.time);
        price = v.findViewById(R.id.price);
        edtUserName.setText(model.getName());
        time.setText(getDateCurrentTimeZone(model.getEnd()) + "");
        DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat(",###.##");
        price.setText(df.format(Integer.parseInt(model.getCurrentPrice())) + "تومان");
        User = v.findViewById(R.id.User);
        Glide.with(context)
                .load(Constants.SERVER + model.getAvatar())
                .placeholder(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
                .signature(new StringSignature(String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis())))
                .into(User);

        if (position == 0) {
            line1.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.winner_1));
        } else {
            line1.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.winner_2));
        }

        commonAction(v);
        return v;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return 6;
    }
```

Comment: provide your adapter code.

Comment: @Heisen-Berg, please see my update codes and help me

Comment: Make sure your array should have 6 items

Comment: show activity where you are inserting data in list ?

Comment: `java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0` You're trying to get the first element from an empty array!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When there is no Element in Your ArrayList `objects` (or Data Have Less than 6 members) or data `IndexOutOfBound` exception will Occur

**Try This**

```
@Override
public int getCount() {
    if(objects.size() < 6){
        return objects.size();
    }
    else{
        return 6;
    }
}
```

### UPDATE

Declare :

```
private ArrayList<Bid> objects = null;
```

In Constructor

```
this.objects = objects
```

Comment: @pom Check Update

Comment: @pom `@NonNull ArrayList<Bid> objects` i mean this objects

Comment: Hope it Worked.Happy Coding. :)

Answer (score 1):

UPDATE:

First you should have your `datas` list declared as a member variable:

`private ArrayList<Bid> datas = null;`

Then in the constructor initialize your `datas` arrays with the constructor argument as below:

`datas = objects;`

Then in the `getCount` method do as below:

```
public int getCount() {
    return datas.size() <= 6 ? datas.size : 6;
}
```

ie: if the size ofyour array list is less than or equal to 6, it will return the size, otherwise 6 always. Try this

Comment: please see my update post and help me with my above codes?

Answer (score 0):

You have zero items on your array `java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0,Size: 0`, 
build an array with only 6 items.

if you can write more details about your code

Comment: you are pass an array to the adapter contractor

Comment: `public AuctionDetailBidListAdapter(@NonNull Context context, @LayoutRes int resource, @NonNull ArrayList<Bid> objects)`

make sure the on your main code to pass array with only 6 items

Comment: you can build an array with only 6 items
```
        ArrayList<Integer> ints=new ArrayList<>();
        ints.add(1);
        ints.add(2);
        ints.add(3);
        ints.add(4);
        ints.add(5);
        ints.add(6);
```

Comment: in case you do not know the array item count you can pass only the first 6 items 
```
        ArrayList<Integer> ints=new ArrayList<>();
        ints.add(1);
        ints.add(2);
        ints.add(3);
        ints.add(4);
        ints.add(5);
        ints.add(6);
        ints.add(7);
        ints.add(8);
        
        ints.subList(0,6);
```